# How do we access anchor tag link embedded inside ul and li tags to open the link associated with that tag using selenium with python

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

I need to open the link of that anchor tag with id=ViewInvoice. How do I do that? Attaching the snap of the HTML page.
Snapshot:

[image: the link i want to access]

Here is the snap of what I need to open the highlighted in yellow:

[image: the tab i want to open]

Here is the code:

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe') # Get local session(use webdriver.Chrome() for chrome)
driver.get("the url") # load page from some url

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='PNRId']").send_keys("MDGLRY")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']").click()

link = driver.find_elements_by_id("ViewInvoice")[0]
link.click()

Answer (score 1):

you can get the element by id and then use .click()

```
link = driver.find_element_by_id("ViewInvoice")
link.click()
```

or

```
link = driver.find_elements_by_id("ViewInvoice")[0]
link.click()
```

Comment: Hi, It's not working. It gives an error "JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

Comment: "NtOpenThread: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights. (0xc0000022)
 thread ID 43952 not found in process". This is the error i get in debug error logs. I have tried driver.find_element_by_css_selector("gst-view-print-btn ViewInvoice clsDtmPageInteraction"), but this doesn't work as well.

Comment: Hi, Tried the second solution as well, but the View Invoice doesn't open.

Comment: @AAYUSH LAKHANI can you please help me get the solution?

Comment: It gives the following error **NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ViewInvoice"]"}**.

Comment: @DebanjanB could you please guide me through this?

Comment: The View Invoice link now open but it directs me back to the start page instead of invoice  page. Can anyone guide me through it?

Comment: Can you please help ?@DebanjanB